# Grid Column Header Border Customization

Tags: wpf, gridview, telerik

I am using telerik RadGridView control. I would like to control/style the colors of the left, right, top, and bottom borders of all the different column headers in the grid.
Although a solution seemed to be to put a border within a border like this:-

```
<Border BorderThickness="5,0,0,0" BorderBrush="Green">
    <Border BorderThickness="0,5,0,0" BorderBrush="Red">
        <Border BorderThickness="0,0,5,0" BorderBrush="Pink">
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,5" BorderBrush="Blue">
            </Border>
        </Border>
    </Border>
</Border>
```

But it removes the content of the header of the column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `ContentPresenter` inside which is bound to the header properties.